# camelcase package give error. TypeError: input.replaceAll is not a function

Tags: javascript, replace, typeerror, replaceall, camelcasing

am getting this error when am using the camelcase npm package.

```
>file:///Users/.../using-package-camelcase/node_modules/camelcase/index.js:54
        .replaceAll(SEPARATORS_AND_IDENTIFIER, (_, identifier) => toUpperCase(identifier));   
            ^  
>TypeError: input.replaceAll is not a function
```

> reinstall the package.

Comment: An error message is not a question

Comment: Maybe your `input` does not have `replaceAll`?

Comment: its my first time on stackoverflow,  am trying to get some help because i got stuck.  apologize if my question not clear.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you using node version <15? Because [`String#replaceAll()` is not available in earlier versions](https://node.green/#ES2021-features--String-prototype-replaceAll).

Comment: perfect @VLAZ that was it . i had a old version of node. after i made the update the replaceAll works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to modify the package in node_module>camlecase>index.js and it's working fine.
the error is found in this line:

```
    return input
        .replaceAll(NUMBERS_AND_IDENTIFIER, (match, pattern, offset) => ['_', '-'].includes(input.charAt(offset + match.length)) ? match : toUpperCase(match))
        .replaceAll(SEPARATORS_AND_IDENTIFIER, (_, identifier) => toUpperCase(identifier));
```

TypeError: input.replaceAll is not a function

so i have change the:

> replaceALL() to replace()

```
    return input
        .replace(NUMBERS_AND_IDENTIFIER, (match, pattern, offset) => ['_', '-'].includes(input.charAt(offset + match.length)) ? match : toUpperCase(match))
        .replace(SEPARATORS_AND_IDENTIFIER, (_, identifier) => toUpperCase(identifier));
```

> this helps, the program runs and the error vanished.